# Unit test in truffle fails

Tags: solidity, truffle, testing

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract adding{

  uint256 public total;
  function  add(uint256 val1,uint256 val2) public returns(uint256){
    total = val1+val2;
    return total;
  }
}
```

The above code add two numbers

```
var adding  = artifacts .require("./adding.sol");

contract ('adding', function(accounts){

  it ("it will add two numbers", function(){
    return adding.deployed().then(function(i){
      instance = i ;
      return instance.add(3,4)
    }).then(function(value){
      assert.equal(value,7,"the values of 3 and 4 must be equal to 7" );
    });
  });
});
```

The above code is my unit test but the unit test fails. If I interact with my truffle console it will work

```
  Contract: adding
    1) it will add two numbers
    > No events were emitted


      0 passing (115ms)
      1 failing

      1) Contract: adding
           it will add two numbers:
         AssertionError: the values of 3 and 4 must be equal to 7: expected { Object (tx, receipt, ...) } to equal 7
```

I can see the following error in my console while running **truffle test**

Comment: Try checking `value.toString()`

Comment: i updated my code   but getting same error

passing (105ms)
  1 failing

  1) Contract: adding
       it will add two numbers:

      the values of 3 and 4 must be equal to 7
      + expected - actual

      -[object Object]
      +7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any function that you call which requires a transaction will not return a value, but the transaction receipt. Instead, you can `call` that function, which will simply run the function on the local node, return the result, and not actually emit a transaction.

You would need to change your code to something like this:

```
return instance.add.call(3,4)
```

This will return the *value* from the function rather than the transaction receipt which you are getting back now from `instance.add(3,4)`.

The other option is to make your function a `view` or `pure` function, which does not require a transaction to call and will return the value:

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.23;

contract adding{
  function add(uint256 val1,uint256 val2) public pure returns(uint256){
    uint256 total = val1+val2;
    return total;
  }
}
```

This should work without needing to `call` the function. Here, we made the `total` variable local to the function, so it does not store or read any data on the blockchain itself, and thus can be treated as a `pure` function.

Comment: hi Thanks a  lot can you look after the  following link 

https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/60610/intracting-with-my-d-app-using-frontend-truffle-petbox